# How to start a specific Firefox profile with browse-url?

Tags: web-browser

In command line I can start a specific firefox profile doing someting like that:
`firefox -P my_specific_profile`

Is it possible to configure emacs for use a specific Firefox profile when using `browse-url` command?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look [here](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BrowseUrl#toc8). You'll want to add `"-P my_specific_profile"` to `browse-url-firefox-arguments`, and everything should work.

Comment: Please expand your answer to include the relevant information from the link.

Comment: @Dan this link points to the right section on the page, but Chrome doesn't jump to it for some reason. Firefox goes where it should though.

Comment: We prefer to have self-contained posts for answers so users can get everything they need from the post. Link-only posts are better as comments.

Comment: Provided a comment contains a link with an adequate answer, how does the poster mark the question as answered?

Comment: A `#toc8` Emacs Wiki URL fragment isn't reliable -- that's just whatever the 8th heading is at the time. Add or delete a heading in that range, and you're suddenly linking to something else.